# Email from excel not working in window 8 2013 issue

Tags: excel, vba, windows-8, outlook, surface

Im using the following code and its been working fine. i have updated to a surface pro and know my macro have stop working.

i think it has some think to do will this line in
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

With window 8 i don't think it uses outlook anymore

Has any one else had this problem

Full code below

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()
 Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "help@hiall.com.au"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Inspection"
        .Body = "Inspection n"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If so, on what line? It's true that if your tablet doesn't have Outlook this won't work.

Comment: Hi Doug. Thanks for your help. The line that turn yellow is set outapp= createobject ("outlook.application") I thought because I'm using a surface pro. What is the mail program it uses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Outlook version do you have installed on the PC? Did you check out the Trust Center settings in Outlook?

In general, your code is correct, I don't see anything strange... The [How to automate Outlook from another program](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/201096?wa=wsignin1.0) article describes the required steps for automating Outlook.

Be aware, the Click2Run edition of Office 2010 doesn't support automation. Also you may find the [You receive run-time error 429 when you automate Office applications](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828550) article helpful.